# Is this relation in Boyce-Codd NF?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization

I have a relation `R(a,b,c,d)` where `(a,b)` is a primary key so I have the determinant `a,b -> c,d`.
In addition to that I have the following determinants: `a,c -> b,d` and `a,d -> b`.

Let's be ok that this relation is in 3NF.
I'm wondering if it's in BCNF or not. I was using a definition for the BCNF that recognize:

> a relation is in BCNF if it's in 3NF and there's no determinant `X -> Y` such as X is non-key attributes and Y is a part (or the totality) of the key

which is not applicable in my case for the determinant `a,d -> b` for example. Another definition is that

> A relation, R, is in BCNF iff for every nontrivial FD (X->A) satisfied
>   by R the following condition is true:
>
> (a) X is a superkey for R

which left me undecided insofar as in `a,d->b` it's clear that `(a,d)` is not a superkey (nor a key), but we have `(a,d)` clearly a key to the relation R!

So, my question is:

- Is the relation R in BCNF or not, and why?
- And what's the right process to determine whether a relation is or isn't in BCNF?

Comment: You say "determinant" but you seem to mean FD (functional dependency). "Key" is unclear, use either CK (candidate key) or superkey. PKs don't matter; but if you *show* there's only one CK then you could call it the PK. Your first definition doesn't make sense & neither does your comment re using it. By the 2nd definition, if you think you have a FD whose determinant is not a superkey, you must think it's not in BCNF--So, what's your problem? Why are you undecided? But--how can (a,d) be not a superkey but be a (candidate?) key--since CKs superkeys. And how is it "not a key" & "clearly a key"?

Answer (score 2):

**About terminology**

You say:

> I have the determinant `a,b -> c,d`

This is wrong therminology. `a,b -> c,d` is a functional dependency (sometimes abbreviated with FD), which has a *determinant* `a,b` (sometimes called left hand side (LHS) of the FD) and a *determinate* `c,d` (sometimes called right hand side, RHS, of the FD). This terminology is used since the values of the attributes `a,b` uniquely determinate the values of the attributes `c,d`.

**About the key**

The information that:

> (a,b) is a primary key

can be irrelevant when normalizing a relation when you have enough information about the functional dependencies. From those dependencies you can calcolate which are the *candidate keys*: set of attributes that uniquely determines all the attributes of the relation and such that you cannot remove any attribute from them maintaining this property (in other words, minimal sets of  attributes that uniquely determines all the attributes of the relation). The information about the primary key can be relevant when you have only partial information about the functional dependencies that hold in a relation, but in your case the information about all the (candidate) keys can be derived from the functional dependencies.

In your example, for instance, there are three candidate keys:

```
1. a, b
2. a, c
3. a, d
```

You can verify this fact by computing the closure of the attributes of a candidate key to see if it contains all the attributes. For instance, let's try to calculate the closure of `a,d` (called `a,d *`):

```
1. a,d * = a,d
2. a,d * = a,d,b  (since a, d -> b)
3. a,d * = a,d,b,c (since a, b -> c, d)
```

So `a,d` is a candidate key (which is also a superkey, i.e. a set of attributes that determines all the attributes of the relation).

**About the BCNF**

There are different definitions of BCNF. Using for instance the second one that you cited, all the three dependencies have a determinant which is a candidate key (and so a superkey), and so the relation is in BCNF.

Comment: PK Info isn't irrelevant, it tells you that certain FDs hold & certain FDs don't hold. Knowing the PK & that certain other FDs hold can be enough to answer some questions.